# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError for flask

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application with postgresql and I want to sort the users based on their bestfriend name. To explain the data base it has one to one relationship in bestfriend and I use flask-migrate and Alembic.But got this error,thanx if you could tell me how can I solve it and where is the problem?

> error
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError
>
> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "users_1.name" must appear
> in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 2:
> FROM users JOIN (SELECT users.name AS name, users_1.name AS
>
> ... ^ 'SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name,
> users.age AS users_age, users.email AS users_email,
> users.bestfriend_id AS users_bestfriend_id \nFROM users JOIN (SELECT
> users.name AS name, users_1.name AS fn \nFROM users JOIN users AS
> users_1 ON users_1.id = users.bestfriend_id GROUP BY users.name) AS
> anon_1 ON anon_1.name = users.name ORDER BY anon_1.fn ASC \n LIMIT
> %(param_1)s OFFSET %(param_2)s' {'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 0}

model.py:

```
friends = db.Table('friends',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class Users(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True)
   age= db.Column(db.Integer )
   email = db.Column(db.String(50),index=True, unique= True)
   bestfriend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete ='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
   

   is_bestfriend = db.relationship( 'Users', uselist=False, remote_side=[id], post_update=True)
```

view.py

```
#condition to sort base on bestfriend name                  
    elif request.args.get('sort') == 'bf':
           sortBy = 'bf'
           friend = db.aliased(Users)
           sub = db.session.query(
                   Users.name, friend.name.label('fn')).\
                   join(friend, Users.is_bestfriend).group_by(Users.name).subquery()

           monkey = Users.query.join(sub, sub.c.name == Users.name).\
                        order_by(sub.c.fn.asc()).paginate(page, MONKEYS_PAGE, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add friend.name.label('fn') to the group by

```
join(friend, Users.is_bestfriend).group_by(Users.name).group_by('fn').subquery()
```